# regexp replace _ with - in hive

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql

I have string values that somtimes have two underscores and sometimes one for the country abbreviation like this:

```
Cusco_DE_campaign_Million
Manzan_ES_CA_order_stra
Tijuan_FR_sitc_Mill
```

etc

I want to replace the underscore by a hyphen only when the country abbreviation countains two times a set of capitals (so CA_FR or ES_CA etc)

So the output should like this:

```
Cusco_DE_campaign_Million
Manzan_ES-CA_order_stra
Tijuan_FR_sitc_Mill
```

How would I write this in Hive SQL with regex_replace?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Replace _     preceded by 2 uppercase letters and _ / start of string   
          and followed by 2 uppercase letters and _ / end of string
```

---

```
with t as
(
    select  explode
            (
                array
                (
                    'Cusco_DE_campaign_Million'
                   ,'Manzan_ES_CA_order_stra'
                   ,'Tijuan_FR_sitc_Mill'
                )
            ) as (val)
)
select  regexp_replace (val,'(?<=(^|_)[A-Z]{2})_(?=[A-Z]{2}(_|$))','-')
from    t
;
```

---

```
+---------------------------+
| Cusco_DE_campaign_Million |
+---------------------------+
| Manzan_ES-CA_order_stra   |
+---------------------------+
| Tijuan_FR_sitc_Mill       |
+---------------------------+
```

Comment: Are you still here?